# How to Count Instead of Sum in a ListBox

Tags: vba, userform

I need to select a list box on a form in Excel which contains both numbers and words. I need to use the userform code to Count many numbers are in the selected ListBox. I am using this code:

```
Private Sub RUNButton_Click()
S = 0

For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
If IsNumeric(ListBox1.List(i)) = True Then
S = S + ListBox1.List(i)

End If
Next
MsgBox ("Number quantity " & S)

End Sub
```

But this code sums the numbers, I want to count.

Like if there are `1`, `3`, `5`, and `6` in the ListBox then msgBox would say `4`

How I can get this?

Comment: `S = S + 1` perhaps.

Comment: Omg Thank you very much. I tried to figure this code out for about 7 hours. It's done now, well, thank you very much.